# Prove that for $n=2^k$, $(k \ge 3)$ there are 4 natural numbers less than $n$ that satisfy $b^2 \equiv 9 \pmod n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I think I am close to proving this, but just need a bit of help with some gaps in my understanding.

I found using a recursive function in a small program that it seemed that for $k \ge 3$, I always get 4 solutions to $b^2 \equiv 9 \pmod n$, with the restriction that $b$ is a natural number less than $n$. Now I want to prove this.

Suppose, $$d^2 \equiv 9 \pmod {2^k}$$ 
$$\implies 2^2 \cdot 2^{k-2} |(d-3)(d+3)$$

So there are 4 cases:

Either: $$2^2 |(d-3) \space  and \space 2^{k-2} |(d+3)$$ or
$$2^2 |(d+3) \space  and \space 2^{k-2} |(d-3)$$ or
$$2^2 |(d-3) \space  and \space 2^{k-2} |(d-3)$$ or 
$$2^2 |(d+3) \space  and \space 2^{k-2} |(d+3)$$

So there are 4 choices $d$s for all $k \ge 3$

I'm not sure if this is a sufficient proof? Because I don't see why I couldn't have written $2^k = 2\cdot 2^{k-1}$ - or does this not matter? Would greatly appreciate any help/hints on this!

Many thanks in advance.

**Added:** Thinking more about this, it seems to follow that in the form $2^k = 2\cdot 2^{k-1}$, then $ 2| d-1$ and $ 2| d+1$ as well - not sure if this is getting me closer?

Comment: Hi Will, I haven't learnt Hensel's Lemma in my class - is there a more elementary way to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primes other than $2$ and $3$ were dealt with in another question, so we work with the primes $2$ and $3$ only. (The question asks only about $p=2$. The case $p=3$ is thrown in because it uses a similar technique.)

There are $2$ solutions modulo $2$, and also $2$ solutions modulo $4$. Now we deal with $2^k$ for $k\ge 3$.

It is clear that $x$ must be odd. Since $x+3$ and $x-3$ differ by $6$, one of them is congruent to $2$ modulo $4$, so contributes at most one $2$, while the other must contribute $2^k$ or $2^{k-1}$ of them. Thus the solutions are $x-3\equiv 2^{k-1}\pmod{2^k}$ and $x-3\equiv 0\pmod{2^k}$ and $x+3\equiv 2^{k-1}\pmod{2^k}$ and $x+3\equiv 0\pmod{2^k}$, a total of $4$.

For $p=3$, it is easy to make a list of all solutions when $k=1$ and when $k=2$. We now deal with $k\ge 3$.

Since $x+3$ and $x-3$ differ by $6$, one of them contributes precisely one $3$, and thus the other must contribute $3^{k-1}$ or $3^k$.

Suppose that $x+3$ contributes only one $3$. Then $x-3\equiv 3^{k-1}\pmod{3^k}$ or $x-3\equiv 2\cdot 3^{k-1}\pmod{3^k}$ or $x-3\equiv 0\pmod{3^k}$, which gives $3$ solutions. The same analysis for $x-3$ contributing only one $3$ gives $3$ more. It is not hard to check these are incongruent modulo $p^k$ if $k\ge 3$.