# Prove that there exists only 2 solutions for $x^2 \equiv 9 \pmod {p^k}$, ($p$ an odd prime > 3 and $x$ a natural number < $n$)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

It appears that the only two solutions are always $3$ and $p^k-3$, I want to prove this, here has been my approach, I think I am close but just missing something, would really appreciate any help!!!

Suppose,

$b^2 \equiv 9 \pmod {p^k}$ for ($k \ge 1$)

$\implies b^2 = 9 + cp^k $ for some integer $c$

I want to find $r$ s.t. $(b+rp^k)^2 \equiv 9 \pmod {p^{k+1}}$

(I.e. since $b \equiv \pm 3$, I want $r \equiv \pm 1$ )

By squaring i get,

$(b+rp^k)^2 \equiv  b^2 + 2brp^k + r^2p^{2k} \equiv   9 \pmod {p^{k+1}}$

Substituting $b^2 = 9 + cp^k$ yields,

$9 + cp^k+2brp^k+r^2p^{2k} \equiv 9 \pmod {p^{k+1}}$

$ \implies (c+2br)p^k+r^2p^{2k} \equiv 0 \pmod {p^{k+1}}$

So I need $r$ s.t.

$c+2br \equiv 0 \pmod p$

Since $b \equiv \pm 3$

$ \implies 2(-3)r \equiv -c \pmod p$ or $2(3)r \equiv c \pmod p$

Now I'm kind of stuck, I'm not sure where I need to go from here. I think that if $b\equiv-3$ then I want $r=1$ and if $b\equiv3$ then I want $r=-1$...

I would really appreciate some help! I think I am close!

Comment: You need $p>3$ as $6$ is a solution for $p=k=3$.

Comment: You're right. Thanks, I'll edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p\gt 3$. Note that $x^2\equiv 9\pmod{p^k}$ if and only if $p^k$ divides $(x-3)(x+3)$. But $p$ cannot divide both $x-3$ and $x+3$, else it would divide their difference $6$. So $(x-3)(x+3)$ is divisible by $p^k$ if and only if $p^k$ divides $x-3$ or $p^k$ divides $x+3$. Thus there are two solutions, $x\equiv 3\pmod{p^k}$ and $x\equiv -3\pmod{p^k}$. Thse are clearly incongruent modulo $p^k$.

**Remark:** The situation is more complicated when $p=2$ or $p=3$. Note for example that the congruence $x^2\equiv 9\pmod{2^3}$ has $4$ solutions. So does the congruence $x^2\equiv 9\pmod{3^2}$. A complete analysis for these special primes is not difficult.

Comment: Oh wow, so simple - I made it much more complicated than needed! Yes, indeed I noticed that when $p=2^k$, for $k \ge 3$ there seem to be 4 solutions for all positive integers $k$, But I had trouble trying to prove this as well. I noticed that $x \equiv \pm 3$ was always a solution. Similarly for $p=3^k$,  $k \ge 3$ the number of solutions is always 6. Are the proofs for these done similarly? Thanks so much!

Comment: You are welcome. You may want to ask about $p=2$ and $p=3$ in a separate question. Someone will probably answer quickly. The proofs are similar to the one above, but there are some twists.

Comment: I did actually: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537615/prove-that-for-n-2k-k-ge-3-there-are-4-natural-numbers-less-than-n-th#comment1146831_537615 - Hopefully, can get a good nudge in the right direction soon, but I'll keep working on it! Thanks!

Comment: I did a somewhat informal solution of $p=2$ and $p=3$, in answer to the question you linked to. If we want to find the answer modulo a **product** of prime powers, just count modulo the prime powers and multiply (Chinese Remainder Theorem).

Comment: Oh wow, you have no idea how much you have helped me. That's exactly where I was trying to get to the case of $n$ in general - I knew once I could prove these cases, I could use the CRT to bind them together. Can't thank you enough!

Comment: You are welcome. Note that for $x^2\equiv 25\pmod{5^k}$, we will except at the beginning have $10$ solutions.